# How to create unified clipboard

Tags: clipboard

Working with clipboard can be like a hell. Sometimes `Ctrl+C` just don't work and if you copy some text on, say, web browser you can't normally paste in somewhere else. Especially between Terminal and other programs. Sometmies you have to paste with `Ctrl+Shift+Insert` sometimes `Ctrl+V`.

Is there any way to unify handling clipboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the copy-paste to middle click using `xsel` and `xvkbd`.

First, install the packages:

```
sudo apt-get install xsel xvkbd
```

Now, run the following command:

```
sh -c 'xsel | xvkbd -xsendevent -file - 2>/dev/null'
```

You can also bind this to a keyboard shortcut from *System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts*.

**More on `xsel`:**

Taken from [www.techrepublic.com](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/use-xsel-to-copy-text-between-cli-and-gui/2411):

> The xsel tool, copyfree software available via the software management
>   systems of most open source operating systems, is a simple utility
>   meant to serve the need to copy text between the CLI environment and
>   the GUI environment. It effectively acts as a pipeline-like interface
>   between the CLI and the GUI clipboard.

To learn more about `xsel`, either visit the link above or go [here](http://www.kfish.org/software/xsel/).